# sandbox custom qlgenerator (Quick look) plugin

Tags: macos, cocoa, plugins, quicklook

How to sandbox quick look plugin on mavericks?

Currently obtaining following error message:

```
2014-04-14 16:26:50.507 qlmanage[5601:303] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x8b13, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.

2014-04-14 16:26:50.512 qlmanage[5601:303] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x3f0f, name = 'com.apple.CFPasteboardClient'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.

2014-04-14 16:26:50.512 qlmanage[5601:303] Failed to allocate communication port for com.apple.CFPasteboardClient; this is likely due to sandbox restrictions
```

Following entitlement is defined at Xcode's "Code Signing Entitlements" build setting, still observed above error message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.CFPasteboardClient</string>
        <string>com.apple.tsm.portname</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Are you trying to debug your .qlgenerator plugin by any chance? I'm trying to debug mine and I'm getting this same error (debugger attaches, but it exits with error: `lsboxd: Denied process 4446(UNKNOWN) access to shared list com.apple.QuickLookDaemon.LSSharedFileList`). Note that my app and plugins aren't signed or sandboxed at all, so I think the error is talking about `qlmanage` being sandboxed, not your app or .qlenerator plugin (in other words, I don't think adding exceptions to your entitlements will make any difference).

Comment: Yes, I got those errors while debugging qlgenerator. How to resolve those errors, if not by adding into entitlements? I got that entitlements from one of the posts in apple discussion.

Comment: I'm getting these same errors.  I have no entitlements.  I'm not Code Signing.  I'm on Xcode 6.2 and OS X 10.10.2, and I can not for the life of me figure out how to make a QuickLook plugin work.  The existing answer isn't even remotely helpful...

Comment: any updates here? same issue

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't solve the original issue let me add some updates on the current status of standalone QuickLook plugins development in 2019 that could have saved me a lot of time when I reached this answer.

- The `com.apple.tsm.portname` error is still there but it doesn't seem to cause issues once the plugin is installed in one of the `Library/Quicklook` locations. The plugin will work anyway.
- If you are developing a standalone plugin (not inside an app) you wouldn't even have entitlements, so don't try to mess with those to solve this issue.
- Debugging with `qlmanage -p <file>` seems to be completely broken at least in Mojave if you use the `kUTTypeHTML` data representation (`kUTTypeRTF` works), nothing is displayed but when you copy the plugin under Library it will work normally...
- Still impossible to use Swift to implement the generators (the last officially provided motivation points to lack of ABI stability (lol))

Answer (score -1):

Quicklook plugins don't support entitlement.

You can try to modify manually the sandbox profile and try to change the rule.

Sandbox profile for quicklook are in `/usr/share/sandbox` where you can check the `quicklook-satellite.sb` and `quicklookd.sb` profile.

I hope this info can help you.

I had some problem on my outlook 2011 quicklook plugins and I resolved modifing the uicklook-satellite.sb

You can help take a look to this document: [FGOUTLOOK2011Manual.pdf](http://www.germinara.it/download/FGOUTLOOK2011Manual.pdf).

Comment: Would this make it nearly impossible to distribute the plugin as you can't really ask people to modify their `/usr/share/sandbox/` files??