# How do I run a QuickLook Plugin built with Xcode 5.1?

Tags: xcode, macos, plugins, osx-mavericks

I can't get my QuickLook Plugin to run when built on OSX Mavericks with Xcode 5.1. The meat of the plugin is quite simple (<20 lines of code). It simply makes a system call, and sends the resulting string to `QLPreviewRequestSetDataRepresentation(..)`.

I originally made the project on Snow Leopard or Mt Lion, using Xcode 4.6. I was able to compile and run the project no problem. When I migrated to Mavericks, I was able to copy my old `.qlgenerator` file to `~/Library/QuickLook` and the plugin worked fine. However now I need to re-compile the project with Xcode 5.1. The project uses the default settings provided by Xcode when starting a new QuickLook Plugin project, and like I mentioned, it builds successfully. As far as I can tell, the compiled binary appears fine.

I set up to debug the program as advised in this question: [Debugging Quicklook Plugin in Xcode 4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811547/debugging-quicklook-plugin-in-xcode-4-6). But when running the plugin, I get this output:

```
Testing Quick Look preview with files:
~/my-test-file.nc
2014-09-09 16:52:43.071 qlmanage[46315:303] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x8c27, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2014-09-09 16:52:43.074 qlmanage[46315:303] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x8f4b, name = 'com.apple.CFPasteboardClient'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2014-09-09 16:52:43.074 qlmanage[46315:303] Failed to allocate communication port for com.apple.CFPasteboardClient; this is likely due to sandbox restrictions
```

In addition, if I copy the `.qlgenerator` file (compiled with Xcode 5.1) to `~/Library/QuickLook`, I can't get `qlmanage` to pickup the new generator.

I have also found this question: [QuickLook Plugin Failing with sandboxing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150120/quicklook-plugin-failing-with-sandboxing-error), which seem like it could be related. I read up a bit on how Apple's Sandboxing is supposed to work, but I can't figure out how to add entitlements to a QuickLook Plugin. I can't find the "Capabilities" panel mentioned in Apple's docs for adding entitlements.

**EDIT**: This also appears to be related: [sandbox custom qlgenerator (Quick look) plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058657/sandbox-custom-qlgenerator-quick-look-plugin).

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself. By use of some additional command line options to `qlamange` and a couple `NSLog` statements, I discovered that the plugin when compiled with Xcode 5.1 was actually working fine, but I had a problem with the `UTI` string in the project's `Info.plist` file. This prevented the `qlmanage` from being able to pick up the plugin.

As it turns out, with the UTI strings fixed, when the plugin is run thru Xcode, I still get the sandboxing errors in Xcode's debugging panel, but the plugin works fine. When the plugin is installed in `~/Library/Quicklook` and properly registered with `quicklookd`, there are no errors that show up in the system log, so all appears to be OK.

Comment: For other folks reading this, you might find these Xcode 6 instructions useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27612166/893113